# Spring: HSQL- Failed to execute database script

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to run HSQL with following two scripts and then test it, but each time I get this error which I cannot handle.

> Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 4 of resource class path resource [data.sql]: insert into spittle (spitter_id, spittleText, postedTime) values (2, 'Trying out Spring''s new expression language.', '2010-06-11')

**Update - additional exception that has been thrown:**

> integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; SYS_FK_10108
>   table: SPITTLE

These are my scripts:

schema.sql

```
drop table if exists spittle;
drop table if exists spitter;

create table spitter (
  id identity,
  username varchar(25) not null,
  password varchar(25) not null,
  fullname varchar(100) not null,
  email varchar(50) not null,
  update_by_email boolean not null
);

create table spittle (
  id integer identity primary key,
  spitter_id integer not null,
  spittleText varchar(2000) not null,
  postedTime date not null,
  foreign key (spitter_id) references spitter(id)
);
```

data.sql

```
insert into spitter (username, password, fullname, email, update_by_email) values ('habuma', 'password', 'Craig Walls', 'craig@habuma.com', false);
insert into spitter (username, password, fullname, email, update_by_email) values ('artnames', 'password', 'Art Names', 'artnames@habuma.com', false);

insert into spittle (spitter_id, spittleText, postedTime) values (1, 'Have you read Spring in Action 3? I hear it is awesome!', '2010-06-09');
insert into spittle (spitter_id, spittleText, postedTime) values (2, 'Trying out Spring''s new expression language.', '2010-06-11');
insert into spittle (spitter_id, spittleText, postedTime) values (1, 'Who''s going to SpringOne/2GX this year?', '2010-06-19');
```

appContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:data.sql" />
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

</beans>
```

UnitTest

```
package com.habuma.spitter.persistence;

import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;

public class DataAccessUnitTestTemplate {
    private static EmbeddedDatabase db;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // creates a HSQL in-memory db populated from default scripts classpath:schema.sql and classpath:test-data.sql
        // obviously, this is the 'in-code' method, but the xml should work for Spring managed tests.
        db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().addDefaultScripts().build();     
    }

    @Test
    public void testDataAccess() {
        JdbcSpitterDao jdbc = new JdbcSpitterDao(db);

        System.out.println(jdbc.getSpitterById(1L));

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        db.shutdown();
    }


}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Prepared statement looks like this `SQL_SELECT_SPITTER = "select id, username, fullname from spitter where id = ?"`. But I tested app and it fails on `setUp()` method(commented other too).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can you be more specific ? I'm not sure what I should remove. I updated questions with second exception thas was threw.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It didn't help. But I've just noticed that at the beggining of output there is `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.` Can it be source of my problem ?

Comment: No that is irrelevant.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It seems that the problem lies in `data.sql` in the line that inserts to `spittle` table. I tested same script without inserting to `spittle` and it works. The error is `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; SYS_FK_10108 table: SPITTLE`. I'm not sure but is there really something wrong with the script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script starts the ID column value with 0. You can specify the start value.

```
create table spitter (
  id int generated by default as identity (start with 1) primary key,
  username varchar(25) not null,
  password varchar(25) not null,
  fullname varchar(100) not null,
  email varchar(50) not null,
  update_by_email boolean not null
);
```

Alternatively you can insert the ids explicitly:

```
insert into spitter (id, username, password, fullname, email, update_by_email) values (1, 'habuma', 'password', 'Craig Walls', 'craig@habuma.com', false);
```